# Ureinwohner, Indigene Völker oder anderes?

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice, single-word-request

Ich weiß, dass im Englischen "indigenous people" die angemessene Bezeichnung ist. Welche der Übersetzung ist am respektvollsten?

- Einheimische
- Naturvolk
- Ureinwohner
- indigenes Volk
- Eingeborenenvolk

Danke

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Was hat die eigene Recherche erbracht, worin (für wen) das Problem liegen kann? Bin über die EN-Wiki zur DE gegangen: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigene_V%C3%B6lker. Welche der dort verlinkten Thesen klingt wenig/am respektvollsten?

Comment: "_die angemessene Bezeichnung_" für wen? Je nach Kontext würde ich unterschiedliche Begriffe wählen.

Comment: Fachsprachlich wohl "indigenes Volk" und umgangssprachlich "Ureinwohner". "Einheimische" umfasst mehr. "Naturvolk" finde ich merkwürdig, da es suggeriert, jedes andersartige Volk sei naturfremd. Das muss nicht umbedingt falsch sein, ich finde bloß, dass es unnötig weniger neutral ist. "Eingeborenenvolk" finde ich etwas spezifischer.

Comment: Es erschließt sich mir nicht, inwiefern die verschiedenen Bezeichnungen unterschiedlich respektvoll sein sollten.